# How to ask a question when you want to answer yourself?

Tags: discussion, voting, asking-questions, etiquette, self-answer

I have seen a few times that this website encourages asking questions for which you already have an answer and to post this answer also. I did exactly this on stack overflow providing the code for a certain function.

I must admit that my question was not perfect as "I was not showing what I had tried". Obviously what I had tried was already the solution to the problem, so I posted it only in the answer itself.

Some people have downvoted the question probably because of not being the kind of question of somebody who has really made an effort to find a solution by himself. Therefore my prize for trying to share my code is losing reputation and I feel that discouraging.

Could you point me towards any successful example of somebody answering his own question to see how to do it?
Could you point me out what is so awful about mine? [Calculate the module of a vector, or square root of a number, in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115805/calculate-the-module-of-a-vector-or-square-root-of-a-number-in-vhdl)

Finally, what do you think about somehow locking the voting of the question in the situation in which the user is also answering by himself? I mean that in order to downvote such question the voter is forced to notice that the asker has answered by himself, not trying to get an advantage out of other users in exchange for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak about the details of your question, but it is too broad already for the simple reason there are two questions in one question. That isn't particularly helpful to future readers.

Split the two questions to start with, that will make it anwerable for other users too.

Judging the single close vote (tool recommendation, tutorials, off-site resources), at least one user has a problem with this line: "Does anybody have any suggestion of a simple code to implement these?" I would probably edited that text out myself rather than downvote and vote to close.

What is most important to me is that you put quite some effort in writing the answer. Sometimes it is hard to build a good question around it.

---

Since you asked for an example: Very successful self-answer: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/993547). As you see, very short question. Answer makes up enough though.

Answer (score 2):

> How to ask a question when you want to answer yourself?

Short answer; *exactly* the same as if you were normally asking a question. Same goes for answering that question. Why should there be any special treatment for self answered questions?

> Could you point me out what is so awful about mine?

I can't speak with any authority on the subject but it looks like you're asking at least two distinct questions and you show no research or effort. The fact that your research is the answer doesn't work. Again... Why should there be any special treatment for self answered questions?

Comment: You can disagree with me but regarding the topic of why should it be treated differently. In a self answered question the asker is not trying to take the time from other users for fixing a problem of his own. Therefore is less of an effort to other users than if the question is not self-answered. That's why I was suggesting somekind of special treatment.
About everything else you said, I agree and I have tried to improve my answer

Comment: I understand the argument but even with a self answered question, others can still answer, you're not posting a single tutorial or article or whatever, you're still asking a question and opening that to the community in which you're posting it. People may give you some leeway if you post a good answer but I don't think we should force that.